# FSLex Unknown Error

Tags: f#, fslex

I got some problem with my FSLex which I can't solve... All I know is that fslex.exe exited with code 1...

The F# code at the top was tested in F# Interactive, so the problem isn't there (I can't see how).

Lexer:
http://pastebin.com/qnDnUh59

And Parser.fsi:
http://pastebin.com/sGyLqZbN

Thanks,
Ramon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-zero error means the lexer failed, usually it'll describe the failure too. When I compile, I get `exited with code 1` along with this:

```
Unexpected character '\'

let id = [\w'.']+ 
----------^
```

Lexer doesn't like char literals outside of quotes, and it doesn't understand the meaning of `\w` either. According to [FsLex source code](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/48188#685327), FsLex only understands the following escape sequences:

```
let escape c =
 match c with
 | '\\' -> '\\'
 | '\'' -> '\''
 | 'n' -> '\n'
 | 't' -> '\t'
 | 'b' -> '\b'
 | 'r' -> '\r'
 | c -> c
```

This fixed version of your lexer compiles fine for me: http://pastebin.com/QGNk3VKD

Comment: Bless you! I forgot that the errors that Visual Studio hides can be still seen through command line. Many thanks!